# codeigniter: php file not found while requesting from ajax call

Tags: codeigniter

I have a country list dropdown in my view which is inside applicants folder.
What i am trying to do is get the list of institutions from respective country using this script.

There is a file named getData.php which fetches the institutions and show it in another select box.

The code is working fine, only the path of this php file is not found on ajax request.

I have kept this file inside views/applicants/getData.php and controller/applicants/getData.php but it does not seem working.

My url looks like this while viewing the page
http://localhost/event_final/applicants/register/8

```
function showAssociation(str)
{

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("actData")[removed]=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php echo base_url() ?>applicants/getData.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Can you guide me where I need to move that php file or do i need to give absolute URL.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly access any files directly by URL in Codeigniter, you have to go through a controller.

Just create a controller method that loads the view, or outputs the data from a model, and access it by `site_url('controller_name/method_name')` or by other means.

The way you describe it, just fetching some data, it probably belongs in a Model (but you still would need a controller method to output the data by http request). Have another read through the [user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html) and see if you need to separate the layers of Model View and Controller a bit more.

It's also not correct to use the `.php` extension in your URL, unless you have set it as your `$config['url_suffix']` which is probably not the case.

Comment: ok, so i can't directly access the php file through js also like this xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php echo base_url() ?>applicants/getData.php?q="+str,true);

Comment: No, it's still an http request. You need to route it through a controller. Among other things, this is a huge security benefit.

Comment: Okay i will try by creating a method and btw do i need to pass the method name in js ? I am only echoing in this php file

Comment: There are probably better ways to handle what you're doing, but I don't know without more details. In any case: Yes, you need to provide the URL that maps to the controller method.